# hide state parameter across recursive methods in different classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, recursion

I have a method "doA" in class A that calls method "doB" in class B, which calls again "doA". A map is passed as an argument in every call, which changes in "doB".
That map is needed through all recursive calls, but that's part of the state of a particular implementation, although I actually want class A to be agnostic of that state, since it won't be needed for other implementations, and surely I don't want to just move the exact same problem somewhere else.

```
class A {
    public void doA(Map state)  {
      b.doB(state)
    }
}

class B {
    public void doB(Map state) {
      if (someCondition) {
         a.doA(processState(state))
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what do you mean by preserve reference??

Comment: I changed the description as the reference thing is not really important. What's important is that the state needs to be preserved throughout all the calls and that I don't want A to know anything about that state.

Comment: If I understand correctly. whatever B is doing on the map "state" shouldn't reflect in A. Ideally speaking B should create copy of the parameter "state" and act on it for this case. Instead of acting on the parameter reference directly which will affect A as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that i can think about is to create a temporary map and copy all the elements when you satisfy the condition and de-refer the temporary map after use so that it will be taken care by the garbage collector.